# Xampp is not starting on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, xampp, lampp

I have installed xampp on my ubuntu 17.10, it has been successfully installed but when i start the xampp using `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` it throw errors

> Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.32-0... XAMPP: Starting
>   Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command
>   not found
>
> /opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
>   fail.
>
> XAMPP:  Starting diagnose...   XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's
>   going wrong.   XAMPP:  Please contact our forum
>   http://www.apachefriends.org/f

and more errors

Comment: Have you tried checking if the command `netstat` is installed? If not, try installing that? Also, this question belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to install `netstat` command as prompt said.

`sudo apt-get install net-tools`

Comment: i have just installed net-tools 

`sudo apt install net-tools`
and it's work...

thanks

Comment: Or you can use >>  `sudo apt install net-tools` command